# How to implement Location Automation Field

Tags: autocomplete, street-address

I am wondering how to go about implementing Location Automation Field, as suggested in this article: http://uxmovement.com/forms/new-form-techniques-proven-to-save-time-and-money/

Are there libraries or services that can help me figure out City/State given the zipcode? I know Google has the Geocoder/decoder or Google Places search that could potentially be useful but their Terms of Use mandate that you must use their services in conjunction with displaying the results on their map, which is a weird thing to do when the user is filling out billing info...

Answer (score 0):

Cheers to you for observing TOS. That's good business.

You could use [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com). LiveAddress API supports [city/state and ZIP code lookups](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/zipcode-api). It now has [auto-complete](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/website-forms) as you type an address, too.

I work at SmartyStreets. In fact, we developed the jQuery plugin which does address validation and auto-complete for you. It even supports freeform address fields.

Related question by yours truly, over on UX stack exchange: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/combining-all-the-address-fields-into-one